# RPM ERRORs on a cloud CentOS 5.5 server

Tags: linux, centos5, rpm, munin

I am attempting to add an rpm repo in order to Yum install a Munin node, however i keep getting the following error:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm

Retrieving http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
error: skipping http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error
warning: u 0x117ce80 ctrl 0x117e1f0 nrefs != 0 (download.fedora.redhat.com http)
```

Do you have any input or advice as to what could be causing this issue.. Google doesn't seem to be of much help in identifiying the issue..

Thanks in advance,
Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use epel-release-5-4:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```